# Apache Solr distributed search over SSL

Tags: java, solr, sharding

According to [Solr documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) you can add "shards" parameter for distributed search in the following syntax:

> host:port/base_url[,host:port/base_url]

How can I tell Solr to use https:// ?

Comment: Do you want (1) to setup a shard and make this shard available over https or (2) consume from a shard that is already setup and available over https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer is located in solrconfig.xml of your core:

```
<shardHandlerFactory class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <str name="urlScheme">https://</str>
</shardHandlerFactory>
```

When you defining shards in your query

e.g. `&shards=192.168.0.1:8983/solr/core,192.168.0.2:8983/solr/core`

the shardHandlerFactory will prefix each server with specified value

in our case `https://192.168.0.1:8983/solr/core` and `https://192.168.0.2:8983/solr/core` .

Comment: You'll need to add this inside the request handler you want to use, in our case inside the block  <requestHandler name="/select" ...